# iOS Doing subquery from RLMLinkingObjects

Tags: ios, realm

This is my attachment model.

```
@interface Attachment : RLMObject
@property BOOL isOfflineAvailable;
@property BOOL isStarred;
```

In my category, I set up linking to attachment.

```
@property (readonly) RLMLinkingObjects *relatedAttachments;

+ (NSDictionary *)linkingObjectsProperties {
    return @{
             @"relatedAttachments": [RLMPropertyDescriptor descriptorWithClass:Attachment.class propertyName:@"category"],
             };
}
```

Then, I am trying to query relatedAttachments and take only if isOfflineAvailable is true.

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY relatedAttachments.isOfflineAvailable == YES"];

self.categories = [[Category objectsWithPredicate:pred] sortedResultsUsingProperty:@"id" ascending:YES];
```

Problem is that it is empty (although there is data). How shall I do? If it is not linking object and just RLMArray, it is okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RLMLinkingObjects` represents a collection, just like an array, instead of a single object. As such, trying to call a predicate directly on `relatedAttachments` won't work, because as an array, it won't have the `isOfflineAvailable` property.

Instead, you can use the `SUBQUERY` syntax of `NSPredicate` to query for any objects inside `relatedAttachments` who match that criteria:

```
RLMResults *categories = [Category objectsWhere:@"SUBQUERY(relatedAttachments, $attachment, $attachment.isOfflineAvailable == YES).@count > 0"];
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: urgh..a little wrong.  I need to filter out attachment from relatedAttachments if that attachment  isOfflineAvailable = 0. 

Now it is like I get categories which relatedAttachments array has 2 (isOfflineAvailable = 0) and 1 (isOfflineAvailable = 1).

Comment: Erm, how do you mean exactly? It sounds like the `isOfflineAvailable == YES` needs to have more checks then...